# Oracle DB 12 Temporarily listen to all changes to database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a piece of software that communicates with my Oracle DB, and I want to find out which table/column is updated when I make changes within the software itself (these changes are persisted in a table - but I don't know which one as the DB is huge). I was therefore wondering if it is possible to list all the changes being made to the DB in real-time, that way I can make a change in the software and hopefully see what table that change affected.

(I am using  JDBC driver (ver. 21.1.0.0.0, JDBC4.2)).

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to list all the changes (...) and hopefully see what table that change affected.

Certainly. One option is to create database triggers on tables you're interested in and store log information into your own *log* table(s).

Other, built-in option, is [AUDIT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107) which is used to

> - (...)
> - Track operations on a specific schema object.

Comment: "create database triggers on tables you're interested in and store log"
Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately, I don't know what the table is that is being written to, and because there are 100's of tables it would be difficult to add triggers to every table.
I Will look into auditing though

Comment: I agree; "self-logging" is OK if you want to quickly log something on a single (or a few) tables, but - for hundreds of them, that's out of question. Use AUDIT instead.